# How to get EVERY user token on a PC for SHGetKnownFolderPath?

Tags: winapi

**I'm working on a System Service project with SYSTEM privilege (cleaning utility)... It does not interactive with any user interface.**

My goal is to check files in "Desktop" and "AppData" folders for any user that exists on the PC.

I'm using `NetUserEnum()` to get the user list on the PC. Then I want to get the path of each user's Desktop and AppData with `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`, but I can't find a way to get each user's access token for `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`. Without a token defined in `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`, it returns the path for SYSTEM and not specific users.

Q1. How can I get the token of each user for `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`?

Q2. If no answer for Q1, is there any **documented way** to get the desktop & appdata path of each user in the PC?

I understand this can be achieved with dirty way ---> Registry key with some string replacement. However, the Registry key method is undocumented, which may easily break in future updates to Windows.

---

**Edit Update:**
@RaymondChen Thanks for pointing out that some user profiles may not exist. Also,

**About Q1** : @Remy Lebeau provides a solution with `LogonUser/Ex()`,login to each user with their credentials,might be the only answer that fits the need of Q1.

**About Q2** : There might have no ***documented way*** to achieve this. The only method might have to stick with Windows Registry (`Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`) , as @Remy Lebeau and @Olaf Hess said. I tried to dig more information on Microsoft Community Forum and I got Microsoft would never allow access other users' profile with their native API for security reason. They do not provide APIs that can possibly violate the security rules. Each user profile can only access by its credentials.

btw, I totally understand that "Cleaning utility" aka "Windows-breaking tool", especially when the tool is not being well codded(ex. compatibility problem). For the sake of avoiding to make it become a totally Windows-Destroyer, I tried to use more documented API as possible.

Comment: Somebody needs to sign in the user to get the token. Note that user profiles for users who are not signed in may not exist on the local machine. (See: Roaming user profiles.)

Comment: `SHGetKnowFolderPath()` takes a **logged in** user token. You would have to either 1) log-in to each user account using `LogonUser/Ex()` (if you know their credentials), or 2) get the user's token from an existing logged-in session using `WTSQueryUserToken()`. If a user is not already logged in, and you can't login to their account, then you simply can't access their information via token-based APIs, you will have to resort to the Registry, ie enumerating `HKEY_USERS\<SID>` keys accessing each one's `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` subkey.

Comment: "Cleaning utility" aka "Windows-breaking tool".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Vista with SP1 / Server 2008 and better you can query the existing user profiles using the WMI class [Win32_UserProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886409(v=vs.85).aspx). This allows you to retrieve the profile path and check whether it is a local or roaming profile and to get status information. The rest (retrieving the paths to APPDATA, DESKTOP, etc.) is likely going to involve reading values straight from the registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`).